# Maven игнорирует useUniqueVersions при сборке jar

Tags: maven

Есть maven проект с двумя модулями.

Один содержит некоторый код и собирается в jar.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>full-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>linkable</artifactId>

</project>
```

Второй использует этот jar как зависимость и собирается в запускаемый jar.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>full-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>executable</artifactId>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
              <mainClass>executable.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>my.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>linkable</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Но если открыть запускаемый jar, то в нем окажется следующий манифест.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: ilsu87
Class-Path: linkable-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_111
Main-Class: executable.Main
```

Как видно Class-Path указывает на архив с версией. Либо я что-то не понимаю, либо useUniqueVersions не работает так как ожидается. А я ожидал, что в Class-Path будет linkable.jar

Сборку делаю из Eclipse:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)
Build id: 20161007-1200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из документации [Apache Maven Archiver](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html)

> useUniqueVersions
>
> Whether to use unique timestamp Snapshot versions rather than -SNAPSHOT versions. The default value is true.

Эта опция указывает, заменять ли слово SNAPSHOT в имени файла на уникальную временную метку. Например, при значении **true** в моем случае это могло быть что-то типа **linkable-0.0.1-20170129.145744-25.jar** вместо **linkable-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**

Похоже, что maven игнорирует эту опцию и всегда использует SNAPSHOT.

Но мои ожидания были неверными. Версия при любом значении появляется в Class-Path манифеста. Этого удалось избежать только благодаря установки кастомного формата имени через другие опции.

```
<classpathLayoutType>custom</classpathLayoutType>
<customClasspathLayout>${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}</customClasspathLayout>
```